# Getting the application path in c# windows application

Tags: c#, winforms, path

Suppose I have the following scenario. I have my application residing in

> D:\MyWinForm\

I have

> D:\MyWinForm\DAL
>
> D:\MyWinForm\BLL
>
> D:\MyWinForm\Program.cs
>
> D:\MyWinForm\Form1.cs
>
> D:\MyWinForm\App.config
>
> D:\MyWinForm\ErrorLog\ErrorLog.txt

In the DAL folder (D:\MyWinForm\DAL) I have a `Dal.cs` file

> D:\MyWinForm\DAL\Dal.cs

In this file I have a function that needs to return

> "D:\MyWinForm\ErrorLog\ErrorLog.txt" this path as string.

I have gone through many questions here. But could not find a suitable answer

Comment: Have you tried something along `Path.GetFullPath(@".\ErrorLog\ErrorLog.txt")` ? It will return `"D:\MyWinForm\ErrorLog\ErrorLog.txt"` if your assembly is located at `D:\MyWinForm`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Edit:**

It's common and good practice to store your log path in your `app.config` file. Then you remove the problem that you are having with your log path being relative to your application path. For example:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>   
<configuration>    
  <appSettings>
    <add key="LogPath" value="C:\Logs"/>
  </appSettings>   
</configuration>
```

Then you load this path from your code as follows.

```
string logPath = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["LogPath"];
```

Now you have a centralized place to store your logs.

Further, I recommend looking into [log4net](http://logging.apache.org/log4net/). It is a popular .NET logging framework.

---

```
private string GetErrorLogPath()
{
    return Path.GetFullPath(@".\ErrorLog\ErrorLog.txt")
}
```

[Path.GetFullPath](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.path.getfullpath.aspx)

Comment: What if the application is moved from D:\ to C:\? There's no reason a relative path can't be used here.

Comment: I was literally answering his question "In this file I have a function that needs to return "D:\MyWinForm\ErrorLog\ErrorLog.txt" this path as string."

Comment: @SamLeach don't take offence, but would you also write `public string GetUserName() { return "Sam"; }` as an answer to question "How to get current user name of application?" ?

Comment: @SamLeach The title asked to get the application path and OP laid out their entire folder structure so it seems they were asking for a relative path more than just returning the string. If you make an edit I'll remove the -1 as you've updated the answer. (Can't remove it otherwise as time limit has expired)

Comment: I tried this way 'return Path.GetFullPath(@".\ErrorLog\ErrorLog.txt")' but it still returns 'D:\MyWinForm\bin\Debug\ErrorLog\ErrorLog.txt'

Comment: @IlyaIvanov The answer to "How to get current user name of application?" would certainly not be "Sam". The answer to "I need a function to return Sam as a string" would be. Which is what he asks if you read the question. :)

Comment: Well, OP just gives that string literal as an example. It's like saying "That function need to return Sam, having Sam as an authorized user in Active Directory or whatever". I understand, the question is very vague, but all the requirements are vague and ambiguous. That's why it's very critical to have documented strict requirements... oh well, don't make me start. Anyway, lets try to solve real problem of OP, instead of coming with first solution

Comment: @Nisha because your path is 'D:\MyWinForm\bin\Debug\...'. If you want it to be 'D:\MyWinForm\...' then change your debug publish directory to 'D:\MyWinForm\'

Comment: @Nisha use `Path.GetFullPath(@"\..\..\ErrorLog\ErrorLog.txt")`, this will do the work, but you should consider how you organize your log files. Double dot `..` in path means, that you go one folder up. Two double dot mean you go up two folders `bin\Debug`. You can also use `Path.GetFullPath(@"\...\ErrorLog\ErrorLog.txt")` as Sayse noted. Thanks by the way, I didn't know that.

Comment: @IlyaIvanov - If i remember correctly, 3 dots is 2 folders up **edit** I remembered wrong, sorry, will delete this

Comment: This requirement was for storing an ErrorLog.txt file that logs all exceptions throughout the windows application. So where will I store that single file even if I have different projects like BLL, DAL etc?

Comment: @Nisha - Make a folder in here for your application. `Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.ApplicationData)`

Comment: I got the answer though I am not sure if it is the right one or not. Using Path.GetFullPath(@".\..\..\ErrorLog\ErrorLog.txt") got me the path I needed

Comment: It won't be the right one, this will only work in your development environment, the second you move your application elsewhere it won't work as it will be looking in the wrong directory, either make an error log in your debug folder which will make my answer correct, or make a folder in application data

Comment: @Nisha THE SOLUTION: Put the log path in your app.config and load it from the app.config. This solves your problem. I have updated my answer.

Answer (score 2):

Most of your question is irrelevant because you shouldn't be concerned in the actual `cs`file, it won't matter when its compiled, it looks like you can do

```
Path.Combine(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory,"ErrorLog","ErrorLog.txt");
```

but be weary as not everyone may have access to the program's directory, you may wish to look into using the app data folder